# What does this mean in my program? -exec ls -s {}

Tags: find, ls

`-exec ls -s`  is part of my program just want to know what does `-s {}` mean. This is my whole program, I know what it does:

```
find $root -type f -exec ls -s {} \; | sort -n | tail -n 15 >> ~/prog.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-exec` is an option for `find` which runs a command using the filenames it found. The syntax of `-exec` is:

```
-exec command {} [;|+]
```

The `{}` is replaced by the name of the files (one file per execution of command if `;` is used, multiple files if `+` is used).

`ls -s` prints the size of the file along with the filename.

This can be done entirely in `find`, using the `-printf` option:

```
find "$root" -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | ...
```

Comment: `;` and `+` without backslashes?

Comment: @A.B. `+` can be without backslashes. `;` needs backslash because shell syntax requires it (but not if you call it using other mechanisms, like python's `subprocess.Popen`). It's not part of `find` itself.

Answer (score 1):

This command `find`s files in directory `$root`, then `exec`utes a command on each of them. The command is `ls -s filename` and {} is the placeholder in the command that is replaced by each of the names of the files found in $root.